# Does Lucene need the same Analyzer instance when indexing and when searching?

Tags: java, android, lucene, indexing, analyzer

I'm creating a dictionary app in Android with Lucene. Do I need to supply the same instance of `StandardAnalyzer` when indexing and searching, or can I just supply a new instance for both?

For example, when I'm about to create an index, I do this:

```
Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_36);
IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(directory,
                    new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_36, analyzer));
```

And then, when getting the best fragments of the search term in the top documents, I do this:

```
TokenStream ts = TokenSources.getAnyTokenStream(indexSearcher.getIndexReader(),
                    hits[i].doc, "definition", analyzer);
```

Or can I just replace every usage of `analyzer` with `new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_36)`? I'm asking this because my indexing and search tasks are in different classes and I'd like to keep a minimum number of objects I'm passing across instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definitely use different instances of the same analyzer/tokenizer.

The only requirement is to ensure they behave *exactly* the same way during searching and indexing (e.g. same object constructors should be used, have the same level of data access, etc.).

Comment: To complete the answer, apart from thread-safety, which I'm not sure about, you may also reuse the same analyzer instance for both the indexing and searching. I believe that was the original question.